# Ubuntu 16.04 samba sharing can't change permissions

Tags: networking, 16.04, permissions, samba

I shared a folder on Ubuntu 16.04 to local network and try to set Permissions for "**Other Access**" to "**Create and delete files**"

[image: shared folder]

But after setting "**Others**" to "**Read and write**" as the following figure

[image: setting permissions]

Press "**Change**" and go back to that "**Change Permissions for Enclosed Files...**", the changes seem to be reverted back:

[image: permission reverted]

How to permanently set "**Read and write**" access permissions for everybody?

Btw, the "**Security context**" is always "**unkwown**" - is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

1. use *nautilus* to share a folder, or
2. write directly to the *samba* configuration file here `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

For the first case do this:

1. create a share folder and call it what you want
2. right click on the folder and select local network share
3. on the dialogue box that appears select two things:

   - share this folder, and
   - allow others to create and delete files in this folder
   - [image]
4. Then a file will be created in the location `/var/lib/samba/usershare` with the changes you added, so you can manually change things there.

   - [image]

For the section option you added individual shares to the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[Your Share name goes here]
    path = /your/folder/goes/here
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 777
    directory mask = 777
```

**Note**:

```
To use the above (second method) you will need to un-share any _previously_ shared folder from _option 1_ or that which you had done.
To set permissions of newly created documents / files edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and in the [global] section add :
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

I rather prefer the former but it up to you I guess.

Sources:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1124810
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide
- https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch06.html (excellent article on samba)
- https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Comment: My `/etc/samba/smb.cnf` is originally empty - is that expected? Also, why is there a semicolon on this line `;   browseable = yes` ? tks

Comment: __;__ represents a comment and when you say empty, do you mean __without any__ content what so ever ?

Comment: yes I just open that file expecting there is _something_ in there first, but there isn't. I just copy the config you recommended, then go to nautilus stopping share, then reshare again that folder (also from nautilus)

Comment: After sharing from _nautilus_ do you see a config in `/var/lib/samba/usershares` ? and for the `smb.cnf` they aught to be some content in there!

Comment: sorry my bad it aught to be __smb.conf__ not __smb.cnf__ please take note. See updated answer

Comment: I'll give it another try later on the day. Thanks for informing